# Unit testing android presenter with callback

Tags: android, unit-testing, callback

I want to test a function on the Android presenter that have a callback on it. This is the function:

```
public void findRandomUsers() {
        view.showProgress();
        mDataManager.getRandomUsers(USERS_SEARCH_NUMBER, new Callback<UserList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {
                if(view == null) return;
                view.hideProgress();
                if(response.body().getUsers().isEmpty()){
                    view.showIsEmptyError();
                }
                users = response.body();
                users.setUsers(CheckRemovedUsers.avoidRemoveds(users.getUsers(), removedUsers.getRemovedUsers()));
                users.setUsers(CheckDuplicatedUsers.removeDuplicated(users.getUsers()));
                if(isFirstTime)
                    view.showUsersList(users);
                else
                    view.updateUserList(users);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserList> call, Throwable throwable) {
                if(view == null) return;
                view.hideProgress();
                view.showError(throwable.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

The Callback is a retrofit2.Callback object USERS_SEARCH_NUMBER is an int object. If it is possible I want to control what the callback response to control if when it returns an empty response or it fails it shows the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your achitecture the way, that you have enough seams.
Currently, you are lacking to mock the `Callback<UserList>`. Why won't you have
a `Factory` class, which provides you that callback? Then you can easily stub components.

```
class UserListCallbackFactory {

    public UserListCallbackFactory() {}

    public Callback<UserList> getCallback(Presenter presenter) {
        return new Callback<UserList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {
                presenter.onSuccess(response.body().getUsers());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserList> call, Throwable throwable) {
                presenter.onFailure(throwable);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now, in the constructor of your presenter:

```
class Presenter extends ...  {

    Callback<UserList> userListCallback;
    DataManager dataManager;

    public Presenter(View view, UserListCallbackFactory factory, DataManager dataManager) {
        ...
        userListCallback = factory.getCallback(this, view);
        this.dataManager = dataManager;
        ...
    }

    public void onSuccess(List<User>) {
        ...
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you have enough seams to mock your callback in your unit test class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PresenterTest {

    ...
    @Mock View view;
    @Mock Callback<UserList> userListCallback;
    @Mock UserListCallbackFactory factory;
    @Mock DataManager dataManager;

    @InjectMocks
    Presenter presenter;
    ...

    @Test
    public void succesfulResponse() {
        when(factory.getCallback(presenter)).thenReturn(userListCallback);
        when(dataManager.getRandomUsers(USERS_SEARCH_NUMBER, userListCallback))
                .thenAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                        userListCallback.onSuccess(SOME_LIST);
                        return null;
                    }
                });

        // check that appropriate actions are performed upon successful callback
    }
}
```

Comment: It never fires answer method so it is not doing onSuccess... Anyway userListCallback has Call and Response as arguments and not a userList. You mean to do presenter.onSuccess there?

Comment: You are testing correct functionality of your `Presenter`. You are isolating your SUT (in this case `Presenter`), stubbing all other components, and checking if `Presenter` works correctly under certain action (in this case when data is fetched). To reply your `You mean to do presenter.onSuccess there?` - in that case you will test nothing. The solution I provided is just a sketch, I haven't tested it. But it will give you the whole concept.

Comment: The problem with callback.onResponse is that this has 2 arguments and one of the is retrofit.Response witch I cannot mock. Anyway with the peace of code that you put in your test example it won't fire the answer method.